# How to get values from IGrouping

Tags: c#, linq, select, igrouping

I have a question about `IGrouping` and the `Select()` method.

Let's say I've got an `IEnumerable<IGrouping<int, smth>>` in this way:

```
var groups = list.GroupBy(x => x.ID);
```

where `list` is a `List<smth>`.

And now I need to pass values of each `IGrouping` to another list in some way:

```
foreach (var v in structure)
{
    v.ListOfSmth = groups.Select(...); // <- ???
}
```

---

Can anybody suggest how to get the values (`List<smth>`) from an `IGrouping<int, smth>` in such a context?

Comment: ID is usually an identity field which should be unique, which would make grouping by it useless, if your just trying to remove duplicate data try Distinct() instead. if it was list.GroupBy(x => x.SubID) then it would make sense to use the grouping but in that case you would most likely want to keep the grouping and foreach(var grp in groups){grp.ToList() ; } would do that

Answer (score 359, accepted):

Since `IGrouping<TKey, TElement>` implements `IEnumerable<TElement>`, you can use `SelectMany` to put all the `IEnumerables` back into one `IEnumerable` all together:

```
List<smth> list = new List<smth>();
IEnumerable<IGrouping<int, smth>> groups = list.GroupBy(x => x.id);
IEnumerable<smth> smths = groups.SelectMany(group => group);
List<smth> newList = smths.ToList();
```

Here's an example that builds/runs: https://dotnetfiddle.net/DyuaaP

Video commentary of this solution: https://youtu.be/6BsU1n1KTdo

Comment: Isn't that the same as a normal "orderBy"? List<smth> newList = list .OrderBy(x => x.id).ToList();

Comment: @MorgoZ, the question is about taking the `groups` and getting back to a flat list.

Comment: @MorgoZ, `OrderBy(x => x.id)` will sort them in ascending order by ID. Contrast this with `.GroupBy(x => x.id).SelectMany(group => group)`, which will sort them by order of first appearance of ID.

If the original IDs are in the order: [1,3,2,2,2,3,0], then grouping them and then flattening into one list will put the IDs in the new order: [1,3,3,2,2,2,0].

Comment: It does't work for me.. it says that the type cannot be inferred by the usage

Comment: type cannot be inferred by the usage

Comment: @Revious Do you have an example that doesn't work? 
Here's an example that builds/runs:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/DyuaaP

Comment: @zcoop98, no.  That does not work.  That will give you the first element in each of the groups which is not the desired result: https://dotnetfiddle.net/sXwnGM

Comment: @MattSmith You're completely right, I was solving a different problem. When I wrote that, I was trying to find out how to take a list and remove objects with duplicate IDs, which is exactly what that `.Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault());` statement does in this case: https://dotnetfiddle.net/o4m4lR. But that's not what this question is asking, which I failed see.

Comment: This just doesn't make sense. `SelectMany` will reverse `GroupBy` so it's not what desired and your `newList` is exactly the same as the `list`.

Comment: That wasn't the question.

Comment: This is the highest scored answer, but it does not answer the question.  With all due respect I will have to downvote this.

Answer (score 48):

```
foreach (var v in structure) 
{     
    var group = groups.Single(g => g.Key == v. ??? );
    v.ListOfSmth = group.ToList();
}
```

---

First you need to select the desired group. Then you can use the `ToList` method of on the group. The `IGrouping` is a `IEnumerable` of the values.

Comment: This answer is correct, but I think the question is already wrong. Why convert your `IEnumerable<smth>` to a `List<smth>` in the first place?

Answer (score 26):

More clarified version of above answers:

```
IEnumerable<IGrouping<int, ClassA>> groups = list.GroupBy(x => x.PropertyIntOfClassA);

foreach (var groupingByClassA in groups)
{
    int propertyIntOfClassA = groupingByClassA.Key;

    //iterating through values
    foreach (var classA in groupingByClassA)
    {
        int key = classA.PropertyIntOfClassA;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think so, at least for now.

Comment: Google shows many examples like this, where the enumerating is done by a `foreach` loop. But the question was how to get the list of items itself.

Comment: @KimHomann, I put my answer in 2015. In my opinion, nobody updates their answers (and questions) according to what Google is saying (unless it says something is wrong).

Answer (score 18):

From definition of IGrouping :

```
IGrouping<out TKey, out TElement> : IEnumerable<TElement>, IEnumerable
```

you can just iterate through elements like this:

```
IEnumerable<IGrouping<int, smth>> groups = list.GroupBy(x => x.ID)
foreach(IEnumerable<smth> element in groups)
{
//do something
}
```

Comment: that iterates through he groups not the items in the group

Comment: Oh my mistake, then: 'foreach (smth p in groups.SelectMany(sth => sth))'

Comment: Google shows many examples like this, where the enumerating is done by a foreach loop. But the question was how to get the list of items itself.

Answer (score 12):

```
var groups = list.GroupBy(x => x.ID);
```

> Can anybody suggest how to get the values (List) from an IGrouping<int, smth> in such a context?

"IGrouping<int, smth> group" is actually an IEnumerable with a key, so you either:

- iterate on the group or
- use group.ToList() to convert it to a List

```
foreach (IGrouping<int, smth> group in groups)
{
   var thisIsYourGroupKey = group.Key; 
   List<smth> list = group.ToList();     // or use directly group.foreach
}
```

Comment: Google shows many examples like this, where the enumerating is done by a foreach loop. But the question was how to get the list of items itself.

Answer (score 4):

If you have an `IGrouping<GroupItem, ListItem>`, and you want to access the items of type `ListItem` **of this group** without utilizing a `foreach` loop, it's very simple. The object of type `IGrouping<GroupItem, ListItem>` is of type `IEnumerable<ListItem>` as well, as it is defined as:

```
public interface IGrouping<out TKey, out TElement> : IEnumerable<TElement>, IEnumerable
```

So you can simply say:

```
foreach (IGrouping<GroupItem, ListItem> group in list.GroupBy(x => x.ID))
{
    IEnumerable<ListItem> itemsInThisGroup = group;
    // ...
}
```

If for some reason, it **has** to be a `List<T>` instead of an `IEnumerable<T>`, you can of course still call `itemsInThisGroup.ToList()`. But usually it's better not to if you needn't.

Comment: This is the correct answer. With an explanation of "why".

Answer (score -1):

Simply do this:

```
// this will "split" the list into groups
var groups = list.GroupBy(x => x.ID);

// groups is a "collection of lists"
foreach (var sublist in groups)
{
  // now the sublist is only a part of the original list
  // to get which is the value of ID, you can use sublist.Key
}
```

You don't need `Select().GroupBy(expr)` makes "a list of lists", kind of.

Answer (score -2):

Assume that you have MyPayments class like

```
 public class Mypayment
{
    public int year { get; set; }
    public string month { get; set; }
    public string price { get; set; }
    public bool ispaid { get; set; }
}
```

and you have a list of MyPayments

```
public List<Mypayment> mypayments { get; set; }
```

and you want group the list by year. You can use linq like this:

```
List<List<Mypayment>> mypayments = (from IGrouping<int, Mypayment> item in yearGroup
                                                let mypayments1 = (from _payment in UserProjects.mypayments
                                                                   where _payment.year == item.Key
                                                                   select _payment).ToList()
                                                select mypayments1).ToList();
```