# Convert ToList() to a list of MyObject

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, list

I'm trying to convert a `List` of `MyObject` that I'm doing operation on by using LINQ and turning back to a list of `MyObject`.

```
public class Part
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string DescFr { get; set; }
    public string DescEng { get; set; }
    public string PartNumber{ get; set; }
    public Part(string strID, string strDescFr, string strDescEng, string strPartNumber) 
    {
        this.ID = strID;
        this.DescFr = strDescfr;
        this.DescEng = strDescEng;
        this.PartNumber= strPartNumber;
    }
}
```

So in another class I use that class to create a list of `Part` objects via the database.

```
List<Part> lstParts = DB.Query.GetParts();
```

After that I'm grouping them by description

```
var lstGrouped = lstParts.GroupBy(x => x.DescrFr);
```

EDIT:

```
var lstGrouped = lstParts.GroupBy(x => x.PartNumber);
```

How can I convert back the `lstGrouped` back to `List<Part>`?
I have tried the `ToList()` method and cast it to `List<Part>`, it does not work, giving me an cast error:

> enable to cast object of type

Comment: Why are you grouping, only to go back to an ungrouped collection?

Comment: Well this was only an exemple, but I'm grouping on my PartNumber which can be duplicates. I'll Edit the it

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Not really I just need to show the single PartNumber not douplicates, I know I could group by in the quey but I need all the parts for other instructions, which is why I'm trying to group by using linq,

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/); please tell us what result you are trying to get, why you think “convert back the lstGrouped back to `List<Part>`” is going to do that, and why you would do it in your code instead of whatever `GetParts` calls. Also please post your real code and the real error message; making things up makes it impossible to guess what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since grouping returns an `IEnumerable` of `IGrouping` you can't just transform it back into the sub-list. If you are trying to remove duplicates, just select the first one:

```
List<Part> finalList = lstGrouped.Select(g => g.First()).ToList();
```

If you want *all* the items back (at which point, why did you group them?) then use `SelectMany`

```
List<Part> finalList = lstGrouped.SelectMany(g => g).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

GroupBy returns an `IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TSource>>`so you are no longer working w/ just a list of `TSource` (in your case `Part`), but a list of groupings.

You may want to iterate over the groupings and get the list from each (see [How to get values from IGrouping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8521025/how-to-get-values-from-igrouping)).

Hard to fully answer since I'm not clear on objective (why you would group, just to get the ungrouped list again).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to get distinct items from the list of items. In that case you can either use Distinct method on the original list or you can go with your group approach and do the following -

lstParts.GroupBy(x => x.PartNumber).Select(x=>x.First()).ToList();