# Select common value in navigation table using LINQ lambda expression

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, lambda

I have a table called `InvestigatorGroup` and a table called `InvestigatorGroupUsers` which is used to see what groups have what users. I am trying to get the common investigator group between two users

My query is as follows:

```
    public InvestigatorGroup GetCommonGroup(string userId, string investigatorUserId)
    {
        using (GameDbContext entityContext = new GameDbContext())
        {
            string[] ids = new[] { userId, investigatorUserId };

            return entityContext.InvestigatorGroups
                .Where(i => i.IsTrashed == false)
                .Include(i => i.InvestigatorGroupUsers)
                .Where(i => i.InvestigatorGroupUsers.Any(e => ids.Contains(e.UserId)))
                .OrderByDescending(i => i.InvestigatorGroupId)
                .GroupBy(i => i.InvestigatorGroupId)
                .Where(i => i.Count() > 1)
                .SelectMany(group => group).FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
```

The entity InvestigatorGroup is as follows:

```
public class InvestigatorGroup : IIdentifiableEntity
{
    public InvestigatorGroup()
    {
        this.InvestigatorGroupGames = new HashSet<InvestigatorGroupGame>();
        this.InvestigatorGroupUsers = new HashSet<InvestigatorGroupUser>();
    }

    // Primary key
    public int InvestigatorGroupId { get; set; }
    public string InvestigatorGroupName { get; set; }
    public bool HasGameAssignment { get; set; }
    public string GroupRoleName { get; set; }
    public bool IsTrashed { get; set; }

    // Navigation property
    public virtual ICollection<InvestigatorGroupUser> InvestigatorGroupUsers { get; private set; }
    public virtual ICollection<InvestigatorGroupGame> InvestigatorGroupGames { get; private set; }


    public int EntityId
    {
        get { return InvestigatorGroupId; }
        set { InvestigatorGroupId = value; }
    }

}
```

The problem is that it keeps returning a value of 0. It doesn't see the shared group with a count of 2 between the two users.

I did a test to return the groups (I removed the count>1 condition) and it returned all the groups for both users not only the one they have in common

I believe the issue is with this line: `.Where(i => i.InvestigatorGroupUsers.Any(e => ids.Contains(e.UserId)))`
Thanks for the help!

Comment: And what is or isn't it doing? What's your question exactly?

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: The problem is that it keeps returning a value of 0. It doesn't see the shared group between the two users (if it does, it doesn't see the count of 2). I did a test to return the groups (I removed the count>1 condition) and it seems to return all the groups for both users not only the one they have in common

Comment: I am not sure if this is really an answer per say but you can build and define lambda expressions on the fly with a parent object now in VS 2015.  You just open up an 'Immediate Window' and start expanding an object.  This may help for a narly object like what you have to break it apart in each lambda segment.  Like 'var object = entityContext.InvestigatorGroups'.  Then use the immiediate window to go off of 'object' with things like '.Where()', 'GroupBy()','OrderBy()', etc.  Just a thought if you have access to get VS 2015.

Comment: I don't have VS 2015 =/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've resolved this by changing my query so that it searches for the rows containing one of the UserId's. Then it queries through those selected rows and selects the ones containing the other UserId (InvestigatorUserId). This way only the rows containing both are returned

My new code is as follows:

```
    public InvestigatorGroup GetCommonGroup(string userId, string investigatorUserId)
    {
        using (GameDbContext entityContext = new GameDbContext())
        {
            IEnumerable<InvestigatorGroup> userGroups = entityContext.InvestigatorGroups
                .Where(i => i.IsTrashed == false)
                .Include(i => i.InvestigatorGroupUsers)
                .Where(i => i.InvestigatorGroupUsers.Any(e => e.UserId.Contains(userId)))
                .OrderByDescending(i => i.InvestigatorGroupId);

            return userGroups.Where(i => i.InvestigatorGroupUsers.Any(e => e.UserId.Contains(investigatorUserId))).FirstOrDefault();

        }
    }
```