# How can I return the Value from a .NET IGrouping via a Key?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, igrouping

I'm struggling to figure out how to retrieve the `Value` part of an `IGrouping` instance.

I have the following:

```
IList<IGrouping<string, PurchaseHistory> results = someList.GroupBy(x => x.UserName);
```

And I now wish to iterate through each collection and retrieve the purchase histories for that user (and check if some stuff exists in the collection of purchase histories).

Comment: How about using `foreach`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8521025/how-to-get-values-from-igrouping

Answer (score 6, accepted):

how about a nested loop?

```
IList<IGrouping<string, PurchaseHistory>> results = someList.GroupBy(x => x.UserName);

foreach (IGrouping<string, PurchaseHistory> group in results)
{
    foreach (PurchaseHistory item in group)
    {
        CheckforStuff(item);
    }
}
```

or one loop with linq statement

```
IList<IGrouping<string, PurchaseHistory>> results = someList.GroupBy(x => x.UserName);
foreach (IGrouping<string, PurchaseHistory> group in results)
{
    bool result = group.Any(item => item.PurchasedOn > someDate);
}
```

Comment: Instead of doing a 2nd loop - is there a way to check if the a PurchaseHistory exists which has a ... i donno .. `item.PurchasedOn  > someDate` ?

Comment: Hmm - i tried that ... AH! i tried results.Any(...) .. ooops! it's on the `group.Any(..)`. ta. got it.

Answer (score 0):

Calling..

```
IList<IGrouping<string, PurchaseHistory> results = someList
    .GroupBy(x => x.UserName);
    .Select(result => (result.Key, result.Any(SomeStuffExists)));
```

With..

```
bool SomeStuffExists(PurchaseHistory item)
{
    return ..
}
```

Yields tuples in the likes of..

- ("UserNameX", true)
- ("UserNameY", false)
- ..

Answer (score -2):

This is the way if you want to iterate through all the items

```
foreach (IGrouping<int, YourClass> value in result)
{
    foreach (YourClass obj in value)
    {
      //Some Code here          
    }
}
```

And this is the way if you want to search some thing by key

```
List<YourClass> obj1 = result.Where(a => a.Key 
== 12).SingleOrDefault().Where(b=>b.objId.Equals(125)).ToList();
```

(Key is considered as 'int' in this case)