# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Linq.IGrouping<int, XXX>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<XXX>>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

[image: DB design of the tables]

I'm trying to return `List<QuestionsAndChoices>` in `getAllQuestions()` method but I'm getting this error

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Linq.IGrouping<int, HowWellDoYouKnowMeAPI.Models.models.QuestionsAndChoices>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<HowWellDoYouKnowMeAPI.Models.models.QuestionsAndChoices>
```

GetAllQuestions

```
public List<QuestionsAndChoices> getAllQuestions()
{
    List<QuestionsAndChoices> questionsAndChoices1 = context.quizQuestionAndChoices.
        Join(context.quizQuestions, QandC => QandC.QuizQuestions.QuizQuestionsId, qustions => qustions.QuizQuestionsId, (QandC, qustions) =>
            new
            {
                QandC,
                qustions
            }).
            Join(context.quizChoices, QandC1 => QandC1.QandC.QuizChoicesId, choices => choices.QuizChoicesId, (QandC1, choices) =>
            new QuestionsAndChoices
            {
                QuestionId = QandC1.qustions.QuizQuestionsId,
                Question = QandC1.qustions.Questions,
                Choices = choices,
             }).GroupBy(e => e.QuestionId).ToList();

    return questionsAndChoices1;
}
```

`QuestionsAndChoices` class

```
public class QuestionsAndChoices
    {
        public int QuestionId { get; set; }
        public string Question { get; set; }
         public List<QuizChoices> Choices { get; set; }
    }
```

`QuizQuestionAndChoices` class

```
public class QuizQuestionAndChoices
{
    public int QuizQuestionAndChoicesID { get; set; }
    public int QuizChoicesId { get; set; }
    public int QuizQuestionsId { get; set; }
    public QuizChoices quizChoices { get; set; }
    public QuizQuestions QuizQuestions { get; set; }
}
```

`quizQuestions` class

```
 public class QuizQuestions
 {
     public int QuizQuestionsId { get; set; }
     public string Questions { get; set; }
     public List<QuizzerQCdetails> quizzerQCdetails { get; set; }
     public List<QuizQuestionAndChoices> QuizQuestionAndChoices { get; set; }
 }
```

`QuizChoices` class

```
public class QuizChoices
{
    public int QuizChoicesId { get; set; }
    public string Choice { get; set; }
    public List<QuizzerQCdetails> quizzerQCdetails { get; set; }
    public List<QuizQuestionAndChoices> quizQuestionAndChoices { get; set; 
}
```

I expect output like this

```
{
    "questionId":1,
    "question":"q1",
    "choices":{
        {
        "quizChoicesId":1,
        "choice":"1c1",
        "quizzerQCdetails":null,
        "quizQuestionAndChoices":null
        },
        {
        "quizChoicesId":2,
        "choice":"1c2",
        "quizzerQCdetails":null,
        "quizQuestionAndChoices":null
        }
    }
}
```

but am getting this output
`@IbraHimM.Nada` I have gone trough that code but I get output like this

```
{
"questionId":1,
"question":"q1",
"choices":{
        {
        "quizChoicesId":1,
        "choice":"1c1",
        "quizzerQCdetails":null,
        "quizQuestionAndChoices":null
        }
    }
}
,
{
"questionId":1,
"question":"q1",
"choices":{
        {
        "quizChoicesId":2,
        "choice":"1c2",
        "quizzerQCdetails":null,
        "quizQuestionAndChoices":null
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please check this question i think it will help 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8521025/how-to-get-values-from-igrouping

Comment: @IbraHimM.Nada thanks , i gone through that article but am getting output like the above (updated the question) which is not correct

Comment: Your expected output is wrong.  Shouldn't "choice":"2c1", be "choice":"1c2",

Comment: @jdweng sorry, I updated my code. Thanks ;)

Comment: Why do you have `.GroupBy(e => e.QuestionId)` there? Is it because you expect many questions to have the same ID, and then you want to group all those that share the ID into "groups", and then return a list of such groups? Because that is what you are doing. Then your have a `List<>` of __groupings__ of `QuestionsAndChoices`. That is not a list of simple `QuestionsAndChoices`. Maybe you simply want to remove the `.GroupBy(e => e.QuestionId)` thing? Did you mean `.OrderBy` instead?

Comment: I can't be done with your classes.  For each question there will be multiple answers (right and wrong).  You do not have a List<Answer> for each question.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen i'm trying to group the `choices` with respect to the `questionId`, So i'm trying to grouping  using .GroupBy(e => e.QuestionId)

Comment: @jdweng i update the question with DB design also please check it once its correct

Comment: Looks like your data structure needs some work. Is it set in stone?

Comment: @BlueEyedBehemoth is it? i'm using asp.net code first approach can you suggest me, thanks for your help

Comment: So if five items have ID equal to `42` and three items have ID equal to `666`, what do you expect your final `List<QuestionsAndChoices>` to look like? You will get a "grouping" with five entries having ID `42`, and another grouping for ID `66` with three items in it. Do you want a list of groups of questions-and-choices?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen yes

Comment: Then you simply change `List<QuestionsAndChoices>` into `List<IGrouping<int, QuestionsAndChoices>>` just like the compiler says? You agree that a grouping of XXXs is not an XXX, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following :

```
List<QuestionsAndChoices> questionsAndChoices1 = (
    from qandc in context.quizQuestionAndChoices
    join quest in context.quizQuestions on qandc.QuizQuestionsId equals quest.QuizQuestionsId
    join answers in context.quizChoices on qandc.QuizChoicesId equals answers.QuizChoicesId
    select new { question = quest.Questions, answers = answers })
  .GroupBy(x => x.question)
  .Select(x => new QuestionsAndChoices()
    {
      Question = x.Key,
      Choices = x.Select(y => y.answers).ToList()
    }).ToList();
```

Comment: thanks @jdweng thank you very much, how do we write this query in using Lambda expression.

Comment: Break it into two queries.  The first with everything in the first parenthesis.