# Get Result of GroubBy() as List<List<SomeObject>>

Tags: c#, linq

```
class SomeObject
{
     int Value { get; set; }
     string ID { get; set; }
}

var TheList = List<SomeObject> { ... }

var groupedObjects = TheList.GroupBy(o => o.ID);
```

The return type is `IEnumerable<IGrouping<SomeObject, string, SomeObject>>`
In the Debug "Results View" the Items are grouped correctly.

How can I get `List<List<SomeObject>>` as return?

A simple `ToList()` does obviously not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need two `ToList()`s:

```
TheList.GroupBy(o => o.ID, c => c)
       .Select(g=>g.ToList())
       .ToList();
```

Comment: Nit: I think you can drop the `c => c`? Although granted it is in OP's question

Comment: @canton7 Yes it could be removed, but it doesn't change anything and leaves the original attempt intact (the relevant change is the addition of the `ToList()`s)

Comment: Thanks to you both.  c was indeed unnecessary but how @DStanley mentioned it doesn't change the result.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a similar question with good answers: [How to get values from IGrouping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8521025/how-to-get-values-from-igrouping)

You could try

```
var groupedObjects = TheList.GroupBy(o => o.ID, c => c).SelectMany();
```

Comment: 1) There's no parameterless version of `SelectMany` (so this won't compile), and 2) I'm not sure that this is what they're after: `SelectMany(x => x)` will flatten the groupings out into a single level, whereas OP still wants two levels, they just want them both to be lists