# How do I get to all the other values of my list after I have grouped by in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, grouping

How can I access any of the values not included in the groupby? Must be simple but I can't get to them.

```
var nextGroupedWorklist = from r in finalList
                        where r.Eprt_id.HasValue &&
                        !string.IsNullOrEmpty(r.Perceel_id)
                        group r by new { r.Eprt_id, r.Mutatie_id, r.Hermes_dossier_nr };
```

Only the Key's are accessible
for the sake of ease the finalList is just a list of 20 or so 'columns' that I retrieved from a database.

```
  foreach (var item in nextGroupedWorklist )
            {
              var record = item.Key.
```

I can only find the attributes after Key.

Comment: Inside the loop: `var records = item.Select(record => record).ToArray();`

Comment: Thank you very much Fabio!!!!

Comment: This is not direct answer to your question, but worth looking at it: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8521025/how-to-get-values-from-igrouping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8521025/how-to-get-values-from-igrouping)

Comment: @Fabio - the `Select` is unnecessary if you are doing `ToArray`.

Comment: @NetMage, `Select` is added to "visualise" what is inside `item` ;)

Comment: @Fabio I'd prefer a comment to code in that case :)

Comment: @NetMage, _a comment to code in the comment_ ;)